# How to delete Pandas rows that have been seen before

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, data-cleaning

If I have a table as follows in Pandas Dataframe:

```
Date        Name
15/12/01    John Doe
15/12/01    John Doe
15/12/01    John Doe
15/12/02    Mary Jean
15/12/02    Mary Jean
15/12/02    Mary Jean
```

I would like to delete all instances of John Doe/Mary Jean (or whatever name may be there) with the same date and only keep the latest one. After the operation it would look like this:

```
Date        Name
15/12/01    John Doe
15/12/02    Mary Jean
```

Where the third instance of both John Doe and Mary Jean have been kept and the rest have been deleted. How could I do this in an efficient and fast way in Pandas?

Thanks!

Comment: `drop_duplicates()` : did you try it?

Comment: `df.drop_duplicates()`.

Comment: please see [`df.drop_duplicates()`](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-pandas-dataframe-drop_duplicates/). using the `Keep='Last'` option.

Comment: Thank you to all who responded. Drop duplicates on a subset of columns with the keep last option works!